# SQL/C# Where should i insert my Method

Tags: c#, sql, methods

I make a method that get all the infos respectively with the "project name" selected from a comboBox.

Here's my code:

```
private void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

        conn.Open();

        string query = "select project_name from JO.dbo.Proj left join JO.dbo.Comp on Proj.company_id = Comp.company_id where Proj.company_name = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "'";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(reader["project_name"].ToString());
            }

            reader.Close();  
        }
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

;

```
void getAllInfoProj()
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

    conn.Open();

    string query2 = "select contact_person,contact_no,address from JO.dbo.Proj left join JO.dbo.Comp on Proj.company_id = Comp.company_id where project_name = '" + comboBox2.SelectedItem + "'";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query2, conn);

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            txtAddress.Text = reader["address"].ToString();
            txtContactNum.Text = reader["contact_no"].ToString();
            txtContactPerson.Text = reader["contact_person"].ToString();
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

When I insert this method on the method above it doesn't have any result at all. because I'm trying to autofill those textboxes when I choose a "project name" from comboBox

Comment: ***PLEASE*** use **parametrized queries** - always, no exception. Do ***NOT*** just concatenate together your SQL! This is an invitation for SQL injection attacks.....

Answer (score 1):

You can call the method on `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `comboBox2`

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
        System.EventArgs e)
{
   getAllInfoProj();
}
```

Note: better to use sql Paramemeters instead of inline parameters in the sql statement.

and also in yoour `getAllInfoProj()` you are overwriting textbox text properties in a loop, you can only see the last record value at the end on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to load the textboxes when some selection is change ( a project is selected), therefore you need to handle the event `SelectedIndexChanged` of your `combobox2`. And call your method   `getAllInfoProj()` in that event.